# FLVPlayback/VideoPlayer: How to access VideoPlayer.load() method that accepts 5 parameters?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flvplayback, video-player

I want to use the following `load()` method that accepts five parameters so that I can load a small "excerpt" from a larger video:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/VideoPlayer.html#load()

In particular, the `startTime` and `duration` parameters seem to be what I need, but I am getting errors that seem to indicate that I don't have the right object/version of something, even though the Adobe docs say that it should work.  Here are my steps:

- Start a new, blank FLA document (AS3).
- Drag an FLVPlayback component to the stage and name it vPlayer.
- Create a new layer and add Actionscript in frame 1:

  ```
  import fl.video.*;

  var innerPlayer = vPlayer.getVideoPlayer(vPlayer.activeVideoPlayerIndex);
  trace(innerPlayer); // "[object VideoPlayer]" appears in Output window

  innerPlayer.load(
        "RTMP://..."
      , 0 // totalTime
      , false // isLive
      , 60 // startTime
      , 10 // duration
  );
  ```

This should give me a ten-second clip starting from the one-minute mark, but I keep getting errors like `ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on fl.video::VideoPlayer/load(). Expected 1, got 5.`

I've also tried casting innerPlayer to fl.video.VideoPlayer, but that doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDITS**: Even though I'm on CS4/AS3 and the documentation claims to apply to CS4/AS3, the class files in my "Component Source" folder don't seem to match the documentation.  I also tried this in CS6, and I got *"1137: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected no more than 3."*

@SunilD. - For CS4:  `FLVPlayback.VERSION`=2.1.0.19, and I am targeting Flash Player 10 (the most recent available)+AS3.  For CS6, `FLVPlayback.VERSION`=2.5.0.26, and I am targeting Flash Player 11.4.

In CS4 and CS6, the errors say that VideoPlayer `load()` only requires one argument (with two optional), and `play()` has three optional arguments.  The output of `describeType(innerPlayer)` confirms:

```
<type name="fl.video::VideoPlayer" base="flash.media::Video" isDynamic="false" isFinal="false" isStatic="false">
    ...
  <method name="play" declaredBy="fl.video::VideoPlayer" returnType="void">
    <parameter index="1" type="String" optional="true"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="Number" optional="true"/>
    <parameter index="3" type="Boolean" optional="true"/>
  </method>
    ...
  <method name="load" declaredBy="fl.video::VideoPlayer" returnType="void">
    <parameter index="1" type="String" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="Number" optional="true"/>
    <parameter index="3" type="Boolean" optional="true"/>
  </method>
    ...
</type>
```

Other notes:  Flash CS6 is up to date.  Manually installing the FLVPlayback 2.5 component didn't work.

Comment: well, it seems clear that vPlayer.getVideoPlayer() is not returning an instance of a VideoPlayer.  You can trying casting innerPlayer as such, but that won't work unless vPlayer.getVideoPlayer() actually returns one.  Without seeing more code - it's impossible to comment further.

Comment: @hunter - I added a trace() statement that seems to indicate that it is an instance of VideoPlayer, and when I force a cast, it does not return null.  The code I posted was pretty much everything!  I added an import statement at the top.

Comment: Yikes - what a pain in the a$$.  To be honest, I always work with 100% AS3 (no components), so maybe I'm not the best person to answer.  However, I fired up Flash CS6, and tried your code, and got the same error(s).  I tried to declare and instantiate a VideoPlayer object directly, and the load() function requested 3 params.  Obtaining a VideoPlayer object through FLVPlayback.getVideoPlayer() resulted in load() accepting only 1 param.  I know this doesn't help you much, but at least you know it's not some glitch with your component files.

Comment: I would debug this by taking more steps to figure out exactly what object you're working with. Since the trace() output seems to indicate you have a VideoPlayer object, maybe it's some earlier version of the VideoPlayer API. You might try inspecting the output of `describeType(innerPlayer)` ... (You can see what parameters that `load()` method actually has, or find other clues to confirm what this object actually is). You might also double check your publish settings and, make sure you're publishing a SWF that is targeting as recent a version of Flash Player as possible.

Comment: Not sure how helpful this is, but the FLVPLayback component has a `VERSION` constant. The version # in the docs is 2.1.023. What does `trace(FLVPlayback.VERSION)` output in your environment? How many arguments does your `VideoPlayer.play()` method accept? That should have the same args as the `load()` method... Finally, does it make any difference if you get the player with the `visibleVideoPlayerIndex` instead of `activeVideoPlayerIndex`? Or how about if you set `activePlayerIndex=1` (default is 0) and try to use that?

Comment: **`playerglobal.swc`**? here is detailed manual how to replace it: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/892495

Comment: @SunilD. - I've added the outputs of VERSION and describeType to the main post. vPlayer.activePlayerIndex does not exist, and visibleVideoPlayerIndex did not fix the error. Clearly something is very wrong with my versions/components, or the Adobe docs are very wrong/misleading...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anon, I think this is an issue of poor documentation / too many different products (Flash, Flex, player, flvplayback component) with different versions.

I was able to get the `.load()` call to work with all 5 arguments (and verified that it did start playing at the specified start time), but only by compiling a new `FLVPlayback_116.swc` from the latest Flex SDK source code (Flex 4.6 with `playerglobal.swc` version 11.6).

See my [screenshot](http://onetacoshort.com/temp/FLVPlayback.jpg).

Might as well see if it works for you.  Here's what you'll need to do:

- Remove the FLVPlayback component from your library - this defines conflicting classes with the updated version.
- Download my [FLVPlayback_116.swc](http://onetacoshort.com/temp/FLVPlayback_116.swc) library

  - Or [FLVPlayback_116_air.swc](http://onetacoshort.com/temp/FLVPlayback_116_air.swc) if you're targeting Adobe AIR, not Flash Player / web
- In Flash, open the `File -> ActionScript Settings` dialog, under the library path tab, click 'Browse to SWC file' and locate the `FLVPlayback_116.swc` file you just downloaded.  My screenshot above shows this dialog and how the `FLVPlayback_116.swc` file is listed after being added.
- In the code (see below):

  - You need to set: `fl.video.VideoPlayer.iNCManagerClass = fl.video.NCManager;`
  - Rather than using `innerPlayer = vPlayer.getVideoPlayer` you'll need to use `innerPlayer = new VideoPlayer(width,height)` and then `addChild(innerPlayer)` and `innerPlayer.play()`
  - I had to add the `innerVideo.play()` call to start the video playing (which I assume the GUI would handle)

Here's my code (also visible in the screenshot):

```
import fl.video.*;

fl.video.VideoPlayer.iNCManagerClass = fl.video.NCManager;
var innerPlayer = new VideoPlayer(640,480);
addChild(innerPlayer);

innerPlayer.load(
      "http://10.0.1.3/test.flv"
    , 0 // totalTime
    , false // isLive
    , 5 // startTime
    , 5 // duration
);
innerPlayer.play();
```

Also, you can see that my `describeType` of `VideoPlayer` shows the proper number of arguments:

```
<method name="load" declaredBy="fl.video::VideoPlayer" returnType="void">
  <parameter index="1" type="String" optional="false"/>
  <parameter index="2" type="Number" optional="true"/>
  <parameter index="3" type="Boolean" optional="true"/>
  <parameter index="4" type="Number" optional="true"/>
  <parameter index="5" type="Number" optional="true"/>
  <metadata name="__go_to_definition_help">
    <arg key="pos" value="41308"/>
  </metadata>
</method>

<method name="play" declaredBy="fl.video::VideoPlayer" returnType="void">
  <parameter index="1" type="String" optional="true"/>
  <parameter index="2" type="Number" optional="true"/>
  <parameter index="3" type="Boolean" optional="true"/>
  <parameter index="4" type="Number" optional="true"/>
  <parameter index="5" type="Number" optional="true"/>
  <metadata name="__go_to_definition_help">
    <arg key="pos" value="34410"/>
  </metadata>
</method>
```

**UPDATE:** I've updated the library so that you can instantiate an [FLVPlayback(w,h)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html) and hence apply skins or whatnot -- treat it just like you would the vPlayer in your code above (except I added the width/height constructor args, since the size used to come from the component on-stage).  Instantiate it like so:

```
  var vPlayer:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback(640,480);
  vPlayer.skin = "http://10.0.1.3/skin.swf"; // optional skin
  addChild(vPlayer);
  var innerPlayer = vPlayer.getVideoPlayer(vPlayer.activeVideoPlayerIndex);
  innerPlayer.load(
                   "http://10.0.1.3/test.flv"
                   , 0 // totalTime
                   , false // isLive
                   , 5 // startTime
                   , 5 // duration
                   );
```

Note - to use a skin, I compiled one of the FLA examples from Flash CS6... I tried using a skin I found on the Internet and it didn't work - it was likely compiled for an older version.  See this [skinned screenshot](http://www.onetacoshort.com/temp/flv_skinned.jpg) and download my [skin.swf](http://www.onetacoshort.com/temp/skin.swf).

Good luck, and let me know if you need further info!

Comment: Confirmed that your component and sample code work.  Incredible job!  For completeness sake, can you add the code you would use to skin the player?

Comment: FYI, I added a note about using skins.